# what is main difference in platform.js and webcomponent.js in polymer

Tags: polymer, polymer-starter-kit

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wId1gMzriRE&list=PLLnpHn493BHHbOWwQxtGCVfEgWZxxofyA&index=3

- he uses platform.js and my polymer init setup using webcomponent.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`platform.js` is an older version of `webcomponents.js` (see [announcement](http://webcomponents.org/articles/platformjs-becomes-webcomponentsjs/) from October 2014). It was renamed with the move to Polymer 1.0, I think.
That video is from 2014, so `platform.js` is used. If you follow the up-to-date instructions, you'll use `webcomponents.js`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know they do different things. `platform.js` is a platform detection library, while `webcomponents.js` is a polyfill library.

The polyfill is to provide a consistent functionality and support to Polymer by providing software functionality where OS or Browser support is missing. If you omit it then, for example, your App is likely to work on Chrome but not Safari (depending on the Polymer components you are using) or out of the box on Android but not iOS.

The platform.js library allows browser and platform specific functionality and detection through a consistent, browser agnostic interface.